# What are the differences between these libraries?

Tags: python, camera, opencv

Currently I don't know which library I should use

OpenFace
OpenBR
OpenCV

My system hast to recognize about 10 different persons and it will run on a Raspberry Pi 3 with the Raspberry Pi Camera Module v2. The light conditions will differ and it the system should work with and without glasses. Furthermore it has to recognize a person in less than 2 seconds.

I know that OpenFace uses a different approach on face recognition and the recognition accuracy is better. But will it work on a Raspberry Pi 3 or will it be to slow?

What are the differences between OpenCV and OpenBR? Which one has better accuracy rates?

Comment: Sounds like you're the perfect candidate to put all three to the test :)

Comment: as your questions are specific to opencv, they should posted on http://answers.opencv.org/ or on the main stack over flow site as they have a better chance of getting answered there. any questions or problems specific (hw or sw related) to the RPi belong here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the low down:

- OpenFace is a python system, that will make it inherently slower than a compiled (C, C++) application (like OpenCV and OpenBR) of same computational weight.
- OpenCV is for general computer vision applications
- OpenBR is specifically for Biometric Recognition and uses OpenCV.

Basically, if speed is of the essence for your application, stay away from OpenFace. And unless you have better OpenCV abilities than the OpenBR team, you should stick to using the OpenBR solution. It has a port specifically for Raspbian too.